# Add devices to Ripple of Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

Visual Studio 2015 brings to us an great function is run an Cordova project on browser by using Ripple.

It provides us only 3 virtual-devices.

[image]

We can emulate ours project on other virtual-devices by change the devices Option on brower like this.

[image]

Well, I know something not supported here, and that is the iPad device is not supported by Visual Studio or Ripple.

How to make them support (or add the profile of ) iPad  ?

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess I have figured out the answer.

Just start the emulator with ios after the debug option.
if u select ripple iPhone 5 there, it will work perfectly.
[image]